# Return vs exit в функции при Ajax запросе?

Tags: ajax, php

Добрый день!
Возник следующий вопрос. Если мы используем аякс запрос к нашей функции, то как коректно выйти из неё, что лучше использовать `return` или `exit` ?

Например:

/ *Допустим здесь прошла обработка запроса и вызов функции которая вернет значение аякс запросу* /

```
function answer($var = ''){

if($var){
$var = $var +5;

if($var >10){

echo $var;

/* А вот здесь собственно и вопрос 
 * Что лучше использовать return либо exit
 */
}

}
```

Comment: правильнее сделать return $var, а уже потом, если необходимо, то echo и exit(). Так возможная область применения функции увеличивается.

Comment: Хотя в данном случае результат может быть аналогичен, правильнее использовать return и самостоятельное завершение работы скрипта.

Функция exit() служит для возвращения статус кодов, в основном для передачи  кодов ошибки при аварийном завершении работы скрипта.

Comment: Спасибо за комент, но в данном случае хотелось бы узнать нужно вообще использовать return? 
Мне не нужно возвращать никакие значения т.к. используется только вывод данных который передается аякс запросу. Просто интересует вопрос который давно уже завис в голове, "если мы не возвращаем никакие значения в функции то нужно ли вообще использовать return; либо его можно просто опустить?"
В доке по php.net не на шел собственно ответа на этот вопрос. 
Знаю и использую в скриптах для выхода exit, если функция ничего не возвращает а просто выводит данные. Обе языковые конструкции что return что exit.

Comment: @brother, если вам не нужно ничего возвращать и по коду дальше ничего гарантировано не выполняется и не выводится, использовать return или exit не обязательно

Comment: exit работает как функция только в том случае если ей передают какой-либо параметр в другом это просто языковая конструкция, а return всегда что-то передает значит что-то должен запустить для передачи и хранения значения как я понимаю.

Comment: vanchester  Спасибо! Просто хотелось бы узнать по стандарту написания кода, правильно ли функцию оставлять без return либо exit?

Comment: @brother, из [документации][1]:

>Если конструкция return не указана, 
>то функция вернет значение NULL.

exit - это не то же самое, что return. return - выход из функции/метода, а exit - завершение программы. После выполнения return указатель возвращается в место вызова функции и выполнение программы продолжается до тех пор, пока не закончится код, exit же сразу же прервет выполнение скрипта и завершит работу

 [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: Спасибо вам за комент и за разъяснения;-) Воспользуюсь скорее всего exit; так как дальше нет необходимости, что-либо выполнять или возвращать, а нужно прервать и вывести. Спс всем кто откликнулся! Хорошего вам дня ;-)

Comment: Ну.. я бы все-таки использовал return. Да, ваша функция может быть всегда пишет значение, но это же идеология функций: они должны возвращать значение. Ну вот к примеру в том коде, что вызывает эту функцию:

    answer();

и не ясно, а откуда же взялось то, что в итоге написано на страничке. А вот

    echo answer();

сразу видно, что answer() дает нам какой-то текст ответа, который мы выводим. Более того, сразу уберется путаница, связанная с тем, что и в каком месте находится.

Но вам, как автору, виднее.